# Using two different data-binds on a single element with knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

Is it possible to attach a **click** binding and **visible** binding to one element?

Ie:

```
<button data-bind="click: function, visible: anotherFunction">Test</button>
```

The workaround would be wrapping the button in a div and setting the visible binding to that element, however, I wanted to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Just enclose them in curly braces:

```
<button data-bind="{click: function, visible: anotherFunction}">Test</button>
```

Edit: actually, I don't think you even need the braces, just separate them with commas and you should be good.